# Como fazer downgrade dos compiladores gcc, g++ e gfortran?

Tags: linux, r, gcc, g++

Estou tentando instalar o pacote `mice` no Rstudio, mas a instalação falha e mostra o erro`/usr/bin/ld: -lgfortran not found`. Notei que não existe um diretório chamado `/usr/bin/ld` no meu PC, mas tenho o gfortran instalado. Eu nunca usei o `fortran` na minha vida, mas suponho que o gfortran compila o código do fortran da mesma maneira que o gcc e o g ++ compilam os códigos`C` e `C ++`, respectivamente. Como ouvi dizer que o `R` é construído no C e no Fortran, decidi verificar se há alguma incompatibilidade na versão desses compiladores. Então, rodei:

```
gcc --version
g++ --version
gfortran --version
```

A saída foi:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1 ~ 16.04 ~ ppa1) 7.4.0
g ++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1 ~ 16.04 ~ ppa1) 7.4.0
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1 ~ 16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Como se vê, tenho versões diferentes instaladas. Para resolver isso, executei:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gfortran-4.9
sudo apt-get install --reinstall g ++ - 4.9
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.9
```

No entanto, quando verifico novamente qual versão eu instalei de cada compilação, ainda recebo a mesma saída. Em outras palavras, nenhum dos downgrades entrou em vigor.

Então eu tentei seguir as instruções da resposta a esta [pergunta](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188341/how-can-i-force-an-older-version-of-g-if-i-have-a-newer-version). Assim, rodei:

```
sudo update-alternative --config gcc
```

Isso abre uma tela de diálogo que me pede para selecionar qual versão do gcc eu gostaria de usar como padrão. Eu escolhi `4.9` e depois verifiquei novamente usando`gcc --version` e funciona bem. Ótimo.

No entanto, quando executei o mesmo comando para g++ e gfortran, não tive o mesmo sucesso. Notei, então, que o g++ não está mais instalado no meu PC, pois o comando `gcc --version` retorna `bash: / usr / bin / g ++: no such file or directory`. Eu não sei o que aconteceu, mas acho que minha configuração do g++ está relacionada a isso. Esse é o meu palpite, porque o g++ é executado normalmente quando eu configuro o gcc novamente, usando a versão `7.4` como padrão.

Em relação ao gfortran, meu problema é um pouco diferente. Quando tentei alterar a versão padrão, a shell retornar `error: no alternatives for gfortran`. Depois tentei a instalação do gfortran novamente usando:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.9
```

que retorna:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gfortran-4.9 is already the newest version (4.9.4-2ubuntu1~16.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 408 not upgraded.
```

Ou seja, o OS diz que já tenho o fortran 4.9 instalado, mas quando peço para trocar a versão default ele me diz que não há alternativas, como se de fato eu só tivesse a 5.4.

Foi o que tentei até agora. Eu tenho duas perguntas: 1) Estou no caminho certo para resolver este problema? (caso contrário, o que devo fazer?) 2) Se isso puder resolver meu problema, como posso fazer o downgrade do g ++ e do gfortran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta rodar:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

O `r-base-dev` automaticamente instala a mesma versão de `gcc`, `g++` e `gfortran`, além de colocar cada uma delas como default. Para verificar isso, cheque novamente a versão de cada um dos compiladores. No meu caso:

GCC

```
gcc --version
```

Output:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) 5.5.0 20171010
```

G++

```
g++ --version
```

Output:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) 5.5.0 20171010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc
```

GFORTRAN

```
gfortran --version
```

Output:

```
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) 5.5.0 20171010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```